# Querying SQL Server 2017 graph tables from EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, graph, sql-graph

I'd like to use graph datatables features from EF 6, but after a lot of research, it seems that it's not supported yet. Is stored procedures the only way to go using graph tables from EF at this moment?

Comment: I'd stay away from EF if you want to use the graph features. Having said that, graph data is stored as normal tables so you should be able to query them as you would normal tabular data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out David. I'm building an app that has a couple of graph tables, all others are relational, so I'm already using EF. I just want to do basic filtering on graph tables joined with  relational one's.

Comment: You spurred me on to try and get graphing into EF Core and I started playing with a [fork of the code](https://github.com/WiredUK/EntityFrameworkCore)! It's actually working quite well and I've asked the EF Core team if it's something they would be interested in. There's a related [Github issue here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8527#issuecomment-423489599).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that, as of today, this is not supported.